# How do I store the id of a button a user clicked in local storage in a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-listener

I'm new to Javascript and I'm trying to get the id of the button a user clicked and store the value in localStorage to use it elsewhere in my React component but it's not working as expected. Please what am I doing wrong?
Below is my function

```js
const handleButtonClilck = (button, event) => {
    setButton(button)
    localStorage.setItem("btncourseId", event.target.id)
}
const coursebtn = localStorage.getItem("btncourseId")
```

Here is the button:

```
<button id={course.id} onClick={()=> handleButtonClick('chapter')} className="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add Chapter</button>
```

The variable coursebtn is returning null but `{course.id}` is returning expected value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button id={course.id} onClick={(e)=> handleButtonClick('chapter',e)} 
className="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add Chapter</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Both solutions worked fine.